# How to detect back and menu button on Android? PhoneGap + jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm on jQuery Mobile v1.2.0 and PhoneGap v2.2.0. None of the PhoneGap events seem to be firing however I call it (be it via `document.addEventListener` or `$(document).on`. The back button and menu button detection just doesn't work.

There are other questions like this but so far all I can see are suggestions to either use `document.addEventListener` or use the jQuery approach for adding event listeners but it really doesn't work. Can anybody give me a sure-fire way to detect them?

Here's the `<head>` of my index.html

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jqm/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jqm/jquery.mobile.theme-1.2.0.css" />
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="jqm/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="js/cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).live("pagechange",function(){
            var page = $.mobile.activePage.attr("id");

            document.addEventListener("menubutton", menuKeyDown, true);
            function menuKeyDown() {
                alert('Menu button pressed.');
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: Can you post your head section of your index.html please, i would like to see how it looks like. )

Comment: Hi @Daniel, I have added it now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delete "cordova.js" in project, before uploading to build.phonegap.com. And try this below code.

```
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jqm/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jqm/jquery.mobile.theme-1.2.0.css"/>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jqm/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js"></script>
<script src="js/cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).live("pagechange",function(){
            var page = $.mobile.activePage.attr("id");
        });
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
            document.addEventListener("menubutton", menuKeyDown, true);
        }, false);
        function menuKeyDown() {
                alert('Menu button pressed.');
            }
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: Umm, I don't use build.phonega.com at all, I compile it locally on my computer

Comment: I just tried your code above, seems to work finally. :) So that means there's no way to intermingle this with jQuery Mobile then?